# Error al acceder a una carpeta compartida desde MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, virtualbox

Utilizo mysql workbench en una maquina virtual ubuntu, tengo una carpeta compartida con los scripts de creacion desde mi Windows, el caso es que al ir a abrir un script desde el workbench y seleccionar la carpeta compartida, me dice que no tengo permisos para acceder, sin embargo abrirla desde el explorador de archivos si me deja.